# applying 2's complement in hex string in java

Tags: java, string, hex, twos-complement

i have hex value 03E7 which is string in type.i need to apply 2s compliment in this string.and the resultant hex value should be in string format.i first converted it to binary then converted .is there is any simple method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative numbers are the 2's complement of positive numbers and vice versa, so I suppose you could parse your string into an `int`, multiply by -1, and then parse it back into the resulting hex string.

```
int intVal = Integer.parseInt("03E7", 16);
String twosComplement = Integer.toHexString((-1 * intVal));
```